# electron production build always has frame - macos

Tags: reactjs, electron, electron-builder

When I am running the dev build, or using npm run prod my window renders as expected.

These are my settings in main.js:

```
  mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
    width: 600, height: 1000, show: false, 
    titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset',
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    }
  });
```

But when I run npm run package the resulting .app when opened has the normal borders and title.

Comment: Can you show me the project structure?

Comment: In the production mode, the app is not loading the correct entry point. Such as index.html

Comment: I think the production app is showing just blank page